# On-premises data gateway for SharePoint hosted in azure VMs

Tags: sharepoint-server, azure, on-premise-data-gateway

I'm planning to move our onpremises SharePoint 2019 hosted using AWS to MS Azure VMs. The architecture of the SP farm is as follows: SP front end, SP App, SQL DB & Active directory. similar to AWS architecture currently. I have powerapps and power automate flows that are fetching data from the sharepoint lists using on-premises data gateway. the question is, if I'm going to move to azure, would onpremises data gateway still be required to fetch sharepoint list data using powerapps and power automate. my theory is that on since we're going to utilize azure, all of MS products are going to be in one environment, which it should allow us to fetch data without gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install SharePoint Server on Azure VM, it's like you still have an on-premise version of SharePoint hosted on a IaaS (Infrastructure as a service). **So an on-premise gateway is still needed.**

The only solution to have a direct access between Power Apps, Power Automate and SharePoint is when you use SharePoint Online in Microsoft 365, as this the SaaS (Software as a service) version of SharePoint, managed by Microsoft.

Other thread: [On-Premises Data Gateway design for Data Sources running on an Azure VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/141453/on-premises-data-gateway-design-for-data-sources-r)